# Felt dizziness half an hour after running for 7 minutes

Tags: running, health

I exercise occasionally once in 4-5 days for half an hour. Today I ran for 5 minutes on the treadmill inside a room not too well ventilated. Afterwards I walked at brisk pace for about 500 meters. 10 minutes that  I was having breafast, while in course of breakfast I felt dizzines so much so that I stopped taking breakfast came out of the restaurant and sat in the open under a tree shade. After breathing for a while it felt Okay and I walked back home. Is this a symptom for something grave? What I should I do to ovrcome this at least its recurrence?

Comment: Where were you having breakfast? If you exercise regularly, the place you were dining could have had a gas leak. It's impossible to answer this question with the limited about of data we have to go on.

Comment: Its was a busy restaurants, and I there were lot of persons along with me having breakfast. The chances of gas leak over there seems pretty remote, anyway I should have mentioned that the place where the food was served was at least 20-25 meters away from where it was being cooked. I exercise frequently but not very regularly. But I have not felt anything like this after exercising.

Answer (score 3):

As with all health questions, the answer is to see a doctor. Dizziness could indicate that an insufficient amount of oxygen is reaching your brain. Causes of that can be as benign as being very winded or as serious as a heart problem. A physical examination by a doctor is the only way to know the cause is benign.

Comment: Your explaination seems plausible that insufficient amount of oxygen is reaching the brain.Thanks for your suggestion I am going to do that, as early as possible.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe your blood sugar was a bit off before you started. Try having a small snack an hour before you run and make sure you are sufficiently hydrated beforehand. I doubt it is anything serious, but if it persists, talk to your doctor.

Comment: What kind of snack, I mean snacks could be many things.Usually i tend to put icecream, coffee and other such stuff in that. Please throw more light on that.

Comment: Something with sugar.

Comment: You should try to incorporate some complex sugars into your diet and also try to eat 30 min to 2 hours before exercise. At least, that's what works best for me.

Comment: Maybe this, maybe that. Guesses don't make good answers. And while possibly reassuring, doubts don't make good diagnoses.

Comment: @JohnP So you are suggesting that he should have asked all the relevant data and then only suggested his diagnosis. But I feel his suggestion is good and worth trying, having some sugar before doing exercise can be tried, and seems worthwhile trying.

Comment: @JohnDoe - No, I'm saying it should not have been an answer at all. SE sites are not "ask questions and come up with a dx", nor are they "take your best guess and hope". Yes, it "could be" low blood sugar. It "could be" dehydration. It "could be" hundreds of things from minor to potentially life threatening.